# updating object with form json

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I am trying to convert data to json and then append that data with some javascript function such as `.push` to an object.

I have an example where form data is being appended to html. Rather, I need to push the json to an object.

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
       $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/

Instead of:

```
$('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
```

can I do:

```
var object = JSON.stringify($('slideForm').serializeObject());
someObject.someArray.push(object);
```

When I tried it, it did not seem to work.

Comment: Do you really want to push the json string? Or the object itself? If the latter, just don't stringify.